# Can a hazard ratio take any form?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider harzard ratio
$$
H(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}
$$
where $f(x),F(x)$ are pdf and cdf of a random variable, respectively.

My question is can $H(x)$ take any form?

In other words, if I'm given an arbitrary function $H(x)$, does there always exist a random variable $X\sim f(x)$, whose harzard ratio is $H(x)$?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58046/proof-of-relationship-between-hazard-rate-probability-density-survival-functio  There is exactly a one-to-one mapping between the survival function/CDF/hazard ratio (excluding those measure zero points). Say the support is on the positive real line, then $\displaystyle S(t) = \exp \left\{- \int_0^t h(s) \, \mathrm{d}s\right\}$ - the resulting survival function need to satisfy $S(0) = 1$, $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to+\infty} S(t) = 0$, and $S(t)$ is monotonic non-increasing. The latter condition just require $H$ to be non-negative.

Comment: The first condition is also automatically satisfied, what left is to check that whether  $\displaystyle \int_0^t h(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \to +\infty$ as $t \to +\infty$

Comment: @BGM: that is actually an answer: any integrable non-negative $h(x)$ on the positive reals with an unbounded integral - including  cases where you hit infinity early such as $h(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for  $0 \lt x \lt 1$